# Large recovery partitions

Tags: factory-defaults

Is there any good reason as to why factory restore partitions are generally much larger than they need to be?

Examples I have found in my own experience:

- Dell XPS laptop

  - Partition: 13.67 GB
  - Used: 6.68 GB
- Dell Inspiron laptop

  - Partition: 14.7 GB
  - Used: 7.2 GB
- Toshiba laptop

  - Partition: 15.3 GB
  - Used: 9 GB

In all cases, shrinking the partition to only slightly more than the Used space had no ill effects on future factory restorations.

Why the exorbitant amount of extra space, given that neither of the three computers ever writes any data to the recovery partition? Is there a good reason I'm overlooking?

Comment: One possible reason is that these are simply overdimensioned so they do not have to change a process later on if they get a bigger image.

Comment: If you're knowledgeable about computers and your computer is out of warranty, there's no harm in getting rid of the recovery partition and reclaiming the space.  You'll never need it.

Comment: @Chimneylmp That's not true - a lot of people actually use recovery partitions.

Comment: I stand corrected.  I've never found them useful before, but just having all the drivers in one place is worth keeping the partition.